# How can I find out if the values in an array exist in a Postgres table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I am trying to determine if values in a postgres array field correspond to values in another table.

I have a table: cars

```
id | name | contents
1  | Ford | {1, 3, 5}
```

and table: contents

```
id | name | desc
1  | Phone | ....
2  | Keys  | ....
```

I want to see if the any of the value in contents(field) correspond with any ids in content(table). This is a Postgres database.

Comment: bad way: you need a relation table cars<>--->contents

Comment: It doesnt allow an array between integer[] integer.

Answer (score 0):

select * from contents where id in (select unnest(contents) from cars)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<@` operator (array-contained-by), which is indexable using the `intarray` extension's GiST opclasses:

```
SELECT ...
FROM cars
INNER JOIN contents ON (ARRAY[contents.id] @< cars.contents);
```

or use `= ANY`:

```
SELECT ...
FROM cars
INNER JOIN contents ON (contents.id = ANY (cars.contents));
```

... but this is probably mismodelling; you should probably have a join table between the two tables to model this m:n relationship, not shove it into an array.

See:

- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html
- http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html